# Выборка из таблицы с продуктами по 2 последних продукта из каждой коллекции без использования HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо осуществить выборку товара без использования HAVING я уже мозг сломал. Помогите плиз.
ЗЫ:  поле **date** - тип данных **datetime**
[image: Скрин данных в таблице - поле date - тип данных datetime]

Comment: *без использования HAVING* Каковы причины этого ... ммм ... необычного ограничения?

Comment: тестовое задание

Comment: В принципе стандартно - коррелированный подзапрос с требуемыми сортировкой и лимитом. *тестовое задание* Я бы скорее затруднился найти способ применить тут HAVING не абы как, а именно по делу...

Comment: Извините а пример запрос можете показать?

Comment: @ahel73, Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю подойдёт.

```
Select
     newtest.* 
from (Select 
      *, 
      row_number() over(partition by id_collection order by date desc) as row
From test) as newtest
Where newtest.row in (1,2)
```

Доставите кавычек и остальное. Извините за оформление, набираю с телефона